# debug performance diff of Same code on nearly same cpu/ram

Tags: ubuntu, numpy, windows-7, performance-testing

I wrote a machine learning model which involves quite amount of numerical optimization computation, it's in Python with `Numpy + Scipy.optimize`.

The training process is very slow on a Lenovo Thinkpad X220 (with i5-2520M CPU and 4GB RAM, Ubuntu 14.04 OS), but much faster on a Lenovo Thinkpad X240 (with i5-4200U CPU and 4GB RAM).

I compared the 2 CPU's online, X220 CPU (i5-2520M) has higher operating frequency, but X240 CPU (i5-4200U) has `Haswell` arch. So the performance should pretty much the same, right?

I wonder that why the Python code is so slow on X220 is because the numerical optimization or matrix calculation library is poor on Ubuntu, how should I debug this performance prolem?

Comment: The way you built numpy / scipy is a big factor. Are they both installed straight from same binaries?

Comment: I have found building numpy /scipy yourself using intel MKL or ATLAS gives best results

Comment: @JohnGreenall, I just found out that the Ubuntu is 32-bit, whereas Win7 is 64-bit.